# importing express failed with node

Tags: node.js, cypress

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import logger from "morgan";
import passport from "passport";
import session from "express-session";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import paginate from "express-paginate";

import auth from "./auth";
import userRoutes from "./user-routes";
import contactRoutes from "./contact-routes";
import bankAccountRoutes from "./bankaccount-routes";
import transactionRoutes from "./transaction-routes";
import likeRoutes from "./like-routes";
import commentRoutes from "./comment-routes";
import notificationRoutes from "./notification-routes";
import bankTransferRoutes from "./banktransfer-routes";
import testDataRoutes from "./testdata-routes";
import { checkAuth0Jwt, verifyOktaToken, checkCognitoJwt, checkGoogleJwt } from "./helpers";

require("dotenv").config();

const corsOption = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
};

const app = express();

/* istanbul ignore next */
// @ts-ignore
if (global.__coverage__) {
  require("@cypress/code-coverage/middleware/express")(app);
}

app.use(cors(corsOption));
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "session secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    unset: "destroy",
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(paginate.middleware(+process.env.PAGINATION_PAGE_SIZE!));

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" || process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use("/testData", testDataRoutes);
}

app.use(auth);

/* istanbul ignore if */
if (process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0) {
  app.use(checkAuth0Jwt);
}

/* istanbul ignore if */
if (process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA) {
  app.use(verifyOktaToken);
}

/* istanbul ignore if */
if (process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO) {
  app.use(checkCognitoJwt);
}

/* istanbul ignore if */
if (process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE) {
  app.use(checkGoogleJwt);
}

app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/contacts", contactRoutes);
app.use("/bankAccounts", bankAccountRoutes);
app.use("/transactions", transactionRoutes);
app.use("/likes", likeRoutes);
app.use("/comments", commentRoutes);
app.use("/notifications", notificationRoutes);
app.use("/bankTransfers", bankTransferRoutes);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

app.listen(3001);
```

Above is my app.ts

I tried node backend/app.ts and got the below:

```
C:\Users\home\cypress-realworld-app\backend\app.ts:1
import express from "express";
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

C:\Users\home\cypress-realworld-app>
```

Also tried installing babel/node and esm and both didn't work. This is the official cypress realworld app that is available on github. My question is how do i get the server running? So that I can run the tests. Thank you

How can I get it working? Installing nodemon didn't help too

Comment: `*.ts` is a typescript file, you should use something like `ts-node` to run it or compile it before running via `node`

Comment: C:\Users\home\cypress-realworld-app\backend>npx ts-node app.ts

Unexpected identifier @IhorSakailiuk